# Four-column responsive definition list?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to recreate this layout which I made using a table, but using `<dl>` instead:

[image]

Turns out that table doesn't look so good on mobile. So what I want to do instead is have "Company" pop under "Name" when it can no longer fit in two columns.

I want each half to be 50% of the container, the `<dt>` can be fixed to, say, 125px. The width of the `<dd>` is unknown due to having variable contents.

Here's what I've got:

```css
dl {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

dt {
  width: 125px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<dl class="customer-details-list">
  <dt><i class="mrkn misc-user"></i> Name</dt>
  <dd>Shawn K. South</dd>

  <dt><i class="mrkn misc-hotel"></i> Company</dt>
  <dd>Shinyglowd Co.</dd>

  <dt><i class="mrkn misc-phone"></i> Home</dt>
  <dd>574-202-5192</dd>

  <dt><i class="mrkn misc-phone"></i> Cell</dt>
  <dd>615-761-0744</dd>

  <dt><i class="mrkn misc-envelope"></i> Email</dt>
  <dd>ShawnKSouth@jourrapide.com</dd>

  <dt><i class="mrkn misc-map-marker"></i> Mailing Address</dt>
  <dd>1228 Hidden Pond Road<br> Nashville, TN &nbsp;37214</dd>
</dl>
```

It looks completely messed up, I know. I'm just not sure how to do this while making it responsive.

N.B. I'm not stuck on using `<dl>`. I don't care about semantics, just prettiness :-)

---

I can't get it to flow left-to-right like I want, but this at least lays out the contents nicely:

```css
.customer-details-table {
  column-width: 300px;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.customer-details-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.customer-details-header {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 130px;
}

.customer-details-body {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-content">

  <div class="customer-details-table">
    <div class="customer-details-item">
      <div class="customer-details-header"><i class="mrkn misc-user"></i> Name</div>
      <div class="customer-details-body">Mr XXXXX</div>
    </div>

    <div class="customer-details-item">
      <div class="customer-details-header"><i class="mrkn misc-hotel"></i> Company</div>
      <div class="customer-details-body">Foo234</div>
    </div>

    <div class="customer-details-item">
      <div class="customer-details-header">
        <i class="mrkn misc-phone"></i> Cellular
      </div>
      <div class="customer-details-body">250-661-8888</div>
    </div>

    <div class="customer-details-item">
      <div class="customer-details-header">
        <i class="mrkn misc-phone"></i> Home
      </div>
      <div class="customer-details-body">--</div>
    </div>


    <div class="customer-details-item">
      <div class="customer-details-header"><i class="mrkn misc-envelope"></i> Email</div>
      <div class="customer-details-body">mark+cust1075@example.ca</div>
    </div>

    <div class="customer-details-item">
      <div class="customer-details-header"><i class="mrkn misc-map-marker"></i> Mailing Address</div>
      <div class="customer-details-body">--</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not an expert on flex, so am not able to help here unless you want a non-flex related answer. Looks like you are on the right track, but you need to inline the name and company and then go to a block level when the screen width gets too small.

Comment: @Berdesdan Yeah... I could probably do it with a bunch of breakpoints, but I'm trying to avoid that. I hate breakpoints. Especially on this layout because a whole bunch of stuff shifts around and then it looks stupid at medium-sized resolutions (tablets?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second snippet, use flex to distribute them *"nicely"*.

I've set `flex-basis` to `33%` and `flex-grow` to `0` to make them stay 3 on a row. Using media queries, i set them 2 on a row below `1000px` and 1 per row below `750px`. Change the break-points to suit your needs.

Consider reproducing your case in the question if you need more help applying this.

```css
.customer-details-table {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.customer-details-item {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.customer-details-header {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 130px;
}

.customer-details-body {
  flex: 1;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .customer-details-item {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  } 
}
@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .customer-details-item {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="section-content">

  <div class="customer-details-table">
    <div class="customer-details-item">
      <div class="customer-details-header"><i class="mrkn misc-user"></i> Name</div>
      <div class="customer-details-body">Mr XXXXX</div>
    </div>

    <div class="customer-details-item">
      <div class="customer-details-header"><i class="mrkn misc-hotel"></i> Company</div>
      <div class="customer-details-body">Foo234</div>
    </div>

    <div class="customer-details-item">
      <div class="customer-details-header">
        <i class="mrkn misc-phone"></i> Cellular
      </div>
      <div class="customer-details-body">250-661-8888</div>
    </div>

    <div class="customer-details-item">
      <div class="customer-details-header">
        <i class="mrkn misc-phone"></i> Home
      </div>
      <div class="customer-details-body">--</div>
    </div>


    <div class="customer-details-item">
      <div class="customer-details-header"><i class="mrkn misc-envelope"></i> Email</div>
      <div class="customer-details-body">mark+cust1075@example.ca</div>
    </div>

    <div class="customer-details-item">
      <div class="customer-details-header"><i class="mrkn misc-map-marker"></i> Mailing Address</div>
      <div class="customer-details-body">--</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like that works and flows the way I want. Thank you! I don't love the media queries but this is still the best solution.

Comment: I don't think I have feelings towards `@media` queries. But that doesn't change the fact they are the native (hence faster than anything else) way of applying (or not) CSS based on various conditions. You don't have to love them, but trying to substitute their functionality with anything else would be, most probably, a downside of that particular project. And it's unlikely the substitute would perform better. Happy coding!

Comment: That's not what I meant. Using `column-width`, your browser can determine the number of columns automatically to make it fit. But columns only flow downwards, not LTR. Flex can flow LTR or TTB, but can't do columns. Not sure if CSS grids can be used for this. All of those are native but none of them are expressive enough to achieve the desired effect. --- Actually...now that I think about it, I could do this with CSS grid, except that IE still has ~8.47% market share.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `float: left;` on the `dt` and `dl` elements, and use a wrapper with `column-count: 2`. No flex or other stuff.

And to make it responsive, change `column-count:`to `1` in a media query for smaller screens.

```css
dl {
  margin-top: 0;
}

dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
  float: left;
}

.wrapper {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <dl class="customer-details-list">
    <dt><i class="mrkn misc-user"></i> Name</dt>
    <dd>Shawn K. South</dd>

    <dt><i class="mrkn misc-hotel"></i> Company</dt>
    <dd>Shinyglowd Co.</dd>

    <dt><i class="mrkn misc-phone"></i> Home</dt>
    <dd>574-202-5192</dd>

    <dt><i class="mrkn misc-phone"></i> Cell</dt>
    <dd>615-761-0744</dd>

    <dt><i class="mrkn misc-envelope"></i> Email</dt>
    <dd>ShawnKSouth@jourrapide.com</dd>

    <dt><i class="mrkn misc-map-marker"></i> Mailing Address</dt>
    <dd>1228 Hidden Pond Road<br> Nashville, TN &nbsp;37214</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: Company should be to the right of Name like in the screenshot when there's room for two columns, and then pop underneath when there isn't enough room. That's the tricky part, getting it to flow from left-to-right rather than top-to-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```css
dl {
  display: block;
}

dt {
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

dd {
  float: none;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<dl class="customer-details-list">
  <dt><i class="mrkn misc-user"></i> Name</dt>
  <dd>Shawn K. South</dd>

  <dt><i class="mrkn misc-hotel"></i> Company</dt>
  <dd>Shinyglowd Co.</dd>

  <dt><i class="mrkn misc-phone"></i> Home</dt>
  <dd>574-202-5192</dd>

  <dt><i class="mrkn misc-phone"></i> Cell</dt>
  <dd>615-761-0744</dd>

  <dt><i class="mrkn misc-envelope"></i> Email</dt>
  <dd>ShawnKSouth@jourrapide.com</dd>

  <dt><i class="mrkn misc-map-marker"></i> Mailing Address</dt>
  <dd>1228 Hidden Pond Road<br> Nashville, TN &nbsp;37214</dd>
</dl>
```

it's like this?